# Handling Symfony Collection violations for user data

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony4

I'm writing an API that will take in a JSON string, parse it and return the requested data. I'm using Symfony's Validation component to do this, but I'm having some issues when validating arrays.

For example, if I have this data:

```
{
    "format": {
        "type": "foo"
    }
}
```

Then I can quite easily validate this with PHP code like this:

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
    "fields" => array(
      "format" => new Assert\Collection(array(
        "fields" => array(
          "type" => new Assert\Choice(["foo", "bar"])
        )
      ))
    )
  ));

  $violations = $validator->validate($data, $constraint);

  foreach ($violations as $v) {
      echo $v->getMessage();
  }
```

If `type` is neither `foo`, nor `bar`, then I get a violation. Even if `type` is something exotic like a `DateTime` object, I still get a violation. Easy!

But if I set my data to this:

```
{
    "format": "uh oh"
}
```

Then instead of getting a violation (because `Assert\Collection` expects an array), I get a nasty PHP message:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument of type "array or Traversable and ArrayAccess", "string" given  [..]`

If there a neat way to handle things like this, without needing to try / catch and handle the error manually, and without having to double up on validation (e.g. one validation to check if `format` is an array, then another validation to check if `type` is valid)?

Gist with the full code is here: https://gist.github.com/Grayda/fec0ed7487641645304dee668f2163ac

I'm using Symfony 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, all built-in validators throw an exception when they are expecting an array but receive something else, so you'll have to write your own validator. You can create a custom validator that first checks if the field is an array, and only then runs the rest of the validators.

The constraint:

```
namespace App\Validation;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Composite;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"PROPERTY", "METHOD", "ANNOTATION"})
 */
class IfArray extends Composite
{
    public $message = 'This field should be an array.';

    public $constraints = array();

    public function getDefaultOption()
    {
        return 'constraints';
    }

    public function getRequiredOptions()
    {
        return array('constraints');
    }

    protected function getCompositeOption()
    {
        return 'constraints';
    }
}
```

And the validator:

```
namespace App\Validation;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class IfArrayValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof IfArray) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, __NAMESPACE__.'\IfArray');
        }

        if (null === $value) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_array($value) && !$value instanceof \Traversable) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();

            return;
        }

        $context = $this->context;

        $validator = $context->getValidator()->inContext($context);
        $validator->validate($value, $constraint->constraints);
    }
}
```

Note that this is very similar to the `All` constraint, with the major difference being that if `!is_array($value) && !$value instanceof \Traversable` is `true`, the code will add a violation instead of throwing an exception.

The new constraint can now be used like this:

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
        "fields" => array(
            "format" => new IfArray(array(
                "constraints" => new Assert\Collection(array(
                    "fields" => array(
                        "type" => new Assert\Choice(["foo", "bar"])
                    )
                ))
            )),
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Very easy to understand, and the sample works perfectly. Sad we have to do this, but glad it can be a drop-in solution. Thanks!